# What is the answer to this logic?

Tags: think-different

```
5 7 4 9 8 2 7 
3 8 6 4 7 5 9   
9 6 1 4 5 8 ?
```

My answer is 9, but it is incorrect. Can you help me solve this?

Comment: if you could add in the level and question number to the title, that would be helpful

Comment: What logic did you use to arrive at 9?

Comment: I think the answer might be 7, and that you might have a transcription error in the fifth column.

Comment: The 2 rows has a sum of 42, so I guess the last row should have the same sum. That's why my answer is 9, but it is incorrect.

Comment: I also suspect `7`, but I've never played the game and don't know **for sure**

Comment: The only pattern I was able to find agrees with @Sconibulus, it also gave me 7 for the answer, but doesn't work for the 5th column. if the 8 and 7 are correct in the rows 1&2, the last number should be 6. Hopefully we'll get an edit that clarifies, and also gives us what level/question this is...

Answer (score 4):

The answer is 6.

It's a simple addition formula :

5,749,827
+
3,864,759

---

9,614,58?